# Problems with dual asm dialect project intel/AT&T

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, assembly, intel, inline-assembly

I am working on a project that needs to be compilable with both QNX-Momentics(based on eclipse, g++ 4.6.1 toolchain) and Visual Studio 2010. For some routines I decided to go for manual assembly implementation, as even intrinsics are not well optimized. The first compiler has ATt&T syntax which can be "intelized" using the -masm=intel flag, the second is intel dialect only.

Using the intel-flag, I can surpass notational aspects by a  -- not nice but working -- defined trick:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define _cmd(...) __VA_ARGS__
    __asm {
#else
    #define _cmd(...) #__VA_ARGS__
    asm volatile (
#endif
  // constants
  // set loop counter
  _cmd( xor       eax, eax; )
        :
        :
#ifdef _WIN32
   }
#else
   );
#endif
```

Now, one problem is, that I cannot access local variables or parameters of functions by name using inline AT&T. A hint i got in another thread, using something like

```
register __m128i x asm("xmm6");
```

did not work work local variables, it was assigned to xmm0. Local Variables or parameters not defined by intrinsics result in undefined references in AT&T, so I decided to use bare stack handling, such as

```
_cmd( movupd   xmmword ptr [eax], xmm3; )
```

and encountered a new problem:

Both function parameters and local variables are handled completely different in both dialects. Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
void linearRegression2DAsm(unsigned int p_oNumPoints, T *p_pXcoords, T *p_pYcoords, 
double *oX, double *oY, double *oXY,
double p_oAvgX, double p_oAvgY)
{
unsigned int p_rLoopsize = p_oNumPoints - (p_oNumPoints % 2);
double oAvgX[2];
```

and this simple computation after the define block given above:

```
_cmd( xor       eax, eax; )
// p_pXccoords
_cmd( mov       ecx, dword ptr [ebp+12]; )
// p_pYcoords
_cmd( mov       edx, dword ptr [ebp+16]; )
// p_oAvgX
_cmd( movhpd    xmm6, qword ptr [ebp+20]; )
// p_oAvgY
_cmd( movhpd    xmm7, qword ptr [ebp+28]; )
_cmd( movlpd    xmm6, qword ptr [ebp+20]; )
_cmd( movlpd    xmm7, qword ptr [ebp+20]; )
_cmd( addpd     xmm7, xmm6; )
// result into oAvgX
_cmd( mov eax, [ebp-32]; )
_cmd( movupd   xmmword ptr [ebp-32], xmm7; )
```

The result should be in oAvgX, which works fine with Intel, but does not lead to success using intel flagged AT&T asm compiler.
Second, I am concerned that an additional O2-Flag might optimize other variables, so that the stack is not guaranteed to be build identically on different compilations.

I need inlining how ever, but cannot see any way of addressing the dual dialect problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access local variables by name in GCC's inline assembly it's just that you have to do it differently than how you'd do it in VS2010. At the end of the inline assembly you should/must provide a list of inputs, a list of outputs and a list of "clobbered"; where both the list of inputs and the list of outputs can include local variables. Also note that the list of "clobbered" is very important (the compiler assumes that anything not listed as clobbered or listed as an output will not change, including things like all memory contents, etc).

Relying on accidental things (like what happens to be in which registers, or what happens to be in which memory locations or stack locations) is a severe bug, regardless of which compiler/s you use and regardless of whether it actually works in some limited test case. The only correct way is to rely on the facilities provided for this purpose (e.g. the input/output lists in GCC's inline assembly).

For any non-trivial piece of inline assembly; given that inline assembly is not part of any (C/C++) standard; I'd assume that the only sane way of getting it to work reliably in multiple compilers is to duplicate the inline assembly.

Also note that different OSs have different conventions (e.g. different ABIs, different kernel syscalls, etc). Essentially, (as a worst case) you may need to be doing something like:

```
#ifdef WIN32_VS2010
    /* Inline assembly to suit Visual Studio 2010 for Win32 here */
#elifdef WIN32_ICC
    /* Inline assembly to suit Intel's "ICC" compiler for Win32 here */
#elifdef LINUX_ICC
    /* Inline assembly to suit Intel's "ICC" compiler for Linux here */
#elifdef WIN32_GCC
    /* Inline assembly to suit GCC compiler for Win32 here */
#elifdef LINUX_GCC
    /* Inline assembly to suit GCC compiler for Linux here */
#else
    /* Generate error about unsupported target here */
#endif
```

Comment: Greetings and thanks for your reply. I know about the lists and the clobber lists in at&t/gcc assembly, but how, for instance, can I access variables in the middle of the code block? Use the in list, assign it to some memory and then later access this? And, most important, how can I assign variables to sse registers? I failed trying so far...

Comment: This is a huge secret; but variables are just an illusion - they don't exist. What does exist is addresses and the contents of memory at those addresses; and registers. You may want to tell GCC that an input to your assembly is the address of something (e.g. a "variable") so that your inline assembly can load the data at that address into an SSE register. You may want to tell GCC that an SSE register is an input too (although I'm not sure if GCC supports SSE properly in this way).

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to wrap the variables into a struct, with enough dummy variables to force a clean alignment to 4,8 or 16. Then the relative positions of the members can be calculated with offsetof(struct x, member) and hopefully these numbers could be injected in compile time as compatible strings.

```
#define LOCAL(a) ((offsetof(struct mystruct,a)==0?"0":offsetof(a)==4?"4":"error"))

asm("   push ebp \n\t"
    "   mov ebp, %0 \n\t"
    "   mov %0, " LOCAL(a) "\n\t"   // this would convert to [ebp + 4]
    "   pop ebp   \n\t"
    :"=0" (&my_struct) :::);
```

VC version could begin:

```
asm("   push ebp ");
asm("   lea ebp, struct.a ");
```

Afterwards, same (ugly) syntax and same number of local variables.